# Pandas : Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I got an error :

> ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['Search Query']

No matter what the column name is, it still didn't work.

Here is my code :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = 0
    conn = MongoClient()
    db = conn.dbTweetsTA
    twit = []
    data_query = []
    collectionList = []
    dataB = pd.read_csv('listQuery.csv', usecols=['Search Query'])
    query_list = dataB['Search Query'].tolist()
    dataB.info()
    print(dataB)
```

Here is my csv :

[image]

Printed csv :

[image]

The separator is `\t`, probably that is the problem, but how do I get the column name only ?

Comment: Please include the first several lines of your CSV file _as text_, not as an image. It is likely that the separator is not a comma.

Comment: The separator is `/t`, I'll update it on the question

Comment: You must pass `sep="\t"` to the CSV reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your separator is `\t` which is 2 chars. `read_csv` interprets it as regex. You need escape the `\` and specify raw string. It will use `python` engine on regex, so just specify it to avoid warning

```
dataB = pd.read_csv('listQuery.csv', sep=r'\\t', 
                     usecols=['Search Query'], engine='python')
```